# How to Slice tensor variables dynamically

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow situation. I would like to get a certain type of output using Tensorflow operation.

Suppose we have a tensor variable:

```
"input" = (2, 4, 4)
[[[ 0.6036284   0.0281072   0.78739774  0.79748493]
  [ 0.92121416  0.31211454  0.75201935  0.49418229]
  [ 0.99500716  0.35610485  0.78246456  0.32932794]
  [ 0.44941011  0.33340591  0.56897491  0.16929366]]

 [[ 0.82108098  0.50557786  0.76569009  0.04855939]
  [ 0.55340368  0.11384677  0.63739866  0.09481387]
  [ 0.52711403  0.5621863   0.44211769  0.85780412]
  [ 0.15423198  0.80663997  0.86868405  0.48221472]]]
```

We have another tensor variable that contains the index of elements to be extracted from a.

```
"idx" = (2, 2)
[[2 0]
 [2 0]]
```

I would like to form a quest such that when we slice "input" using "idx" then the resultant outcome is as below. Note, the slice takes place based on the 2nd dimension.

```
Output: (2, 2, 4)
 [[[ 0.99500716  0.35610485  0.78246456  0.32932794]
  [ 0.6036284   0.0281072   0.78739774  0.79748493]]

 [[ 0.52711403  0.5621863   0.44211769  0.85780412]
  [ 0.82108098  0.50557786  0.76569009  0.04855939]]]
```

I would like to achieve similar operation using Tensorflow where the "input" and "idx" are populated dynamically.

One way I can think when we explicitly mention "idx" is:

```
idx = [[[0,2],[0,0]], [[1,2],[1,0]]]
output = tf.gather_nd(input, idx)
```

But I am not sure how to construct idx = [[[0,2],[0,0]], [[1,2],[1,0]]] from dynamically populated idx = [[2 0], [2 0]]

I tried using tf.map_fn using different combinations, but still I couldn't come to a solution.

Any Help will be appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the full indices by:

```
#Use meshgrid to get [[0 0] [1 1]]
mesh = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(indices.shape[1]), tf.range(indices.shape[0]))[1]

#Stack mesh and the idx
full_indices = tf.stack([mesh, indices], axis=2)
#Output
# [[[0 2] [0 0]]
#  [[1 2] [1 0]]]
```